# ASP Doesn't Exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

im currently having an issue with ASP saying that one of the items within my code doesnt exist however it exists within the designer file and is named correctly on both the ASPX and ASPX.CS files and i cannot figure out why this issue is occuring. As it is saying that userLabel does not currently exist and i cannot seem to understand why as my other pages work correctly.

ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Homepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assignment2ASP.Homepage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Logged In Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the Logged In page</p>

<form id="logoutform" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="logoutButton" Text="Logout" runat="server" OnClick="logoutEventMethod" />
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>
    <asp:Label ID="userLabel" Text ="No User" runat="server" />
    </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.CS CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class LoggedIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
String name;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    name = (String)(Session["uname"]);
    if (name == null)
    {
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx", true);
    }
    else
    {
        userLabel.Text = name;
    }
}

protected void logoutEventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["uname"] = null;
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx", true);
}
}
```

Designer File:

```
namespace Assignment2ASP {


public partial class Homepage {

    /// <summary>
    /// logoutform control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm logoutform;

    /// <summary>
    /// logoutButton control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button logoutButton;

    /// <summary>
    /// userLabel control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label userLabel;
}
}
```

Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the class name in the aspx.cs file is different than the one in the designer file. Renaming the class in the code behind file from LoggedIn to Homepage should solve the error.

Comment: How does it differe from the .cs file to the designer file i cannot see how it is named differently as they are both called userLabel.

Comment: In your sample above it reads once *public partial class LoggedIn* and once *public partial class Homepage*. This means that the class in your aspx.cs does have nothing to do with the designer class and therefore does not know the field userLabel.

Comment: I am now also getting this error upon loading the page. 
https://gyazo.com/54dc9b308466ad8edd3d509b66b438de

Comment: Thank you for that i have now fixed that issue however it is now printing the name within the label three times. As shown here: https://gyazo.com/a56549b03dd08425f4ebec5af95acb29

Comment: Nevermind i have also now fixed the issue of it printing the data three times, thank you very much for your solution it fixed my issue!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Label lb = (Label)FindControl("userLabel");
lb.Text = "New text";
```

Comment: No, this should not be necessary.

Comment: I just dont get why it says that it doesn't exist when on my end as far as i can see they are called the same which is userLabel i have tried fixing it using methods i used to fix this error as i had it previously all i did was put a namespace in the Designer file however this has not fixed it with this error.

Comment: Coz when you say CodeBehind="Homepage.aspx.cs" in your aspx page. The system will link your aspx page with that aspx.cs file only. So as @Markus said change your aspx.cs class name to Homepage. That should help. If you don't find the control yet check with my solution of findControl